# Scala/SBT - Documenting Configuration Change for Releases

Tags: documentation, planning, release-management

I'm trying to collect different ways of managing configuration across multiple environments.
I have a requirement to document configuration changes for the deployment plan.

Dev values are defaults in the code and QA manages their own as well so the documenting and sharing of the info is a critical point.

Rather than copy/pasting diffs into tickets, I'm wondering if there is a sharper way to do this. Keeping multiple copies of the config for each env seems to be divergent change. Manually documenting is just hard work and very error prone. Should be copy/pastable. I think templating may be an option but not sure how we'd plug that into build.

Custom code is fine so I guess we could make a new build target if needed. Using scala/sbt but a maven solution or any other would be fine as it can be translated.